# Accessing grouped data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a table of data that contains 2 fields user_id, article_id for users that have written comments against specific articles (many-many relationship implied).

I have grouped the data as follows:

> grouped = df_selected['article_id'].groupby([df_selected['user_id'], df_selected['article_id']])

This essentially gives me counts of comments, per article_ids for a given specific user, for all the users - see table. The resulting object is of type series.

Two things I would like to do:

(1) What is the best way to name the 3rd column and turn the whole object into a molten data format table (i.e. where each 'cell' has information even if 'user_id' is repeated across multiple rows - so in the example of the picture user_ids 2 and 3 would be repeated)?

(2) One thing I want to check is that no user has written more than one comments against a specific article (this is the 3rd column in the pic) - how do I filter by this column to check? (Appreciate I can iterate over the grouped object - but was wondering if there was a vectorised way of doing this...)

What I would like to do is to count the number of user_ids with 1, 2, 3... comments.

Thanks in advance.

```
user_id  article_id  no of comments
6        73          2
43       18          2
         290         2
         311         2
374      763         2
         1539        2
380      690         4
         820         3
         863         2
387      575         2
         575         2
         690         2
         702         2
```

Comment: please copy and paste the output from your intepreter (that way we can do the same, and use your example), rather than (unusable) screenshot.

Comment: How do I format the data into a table in SO?

Comment: Just plain text, with spaces. And if you prepend each line with four spaces, the text will display as in code style.

Comment: @user7289 same effect highlight and ctrl+k

Comment: @user7289 It looks like you posted a `MultiIndex`. Can you post the data as `DataFrame` instead?